# "Attribute itemprop not allowed on element meta at this point"

Tags: html, w3c-validation, microdata

I'm getting the error from the title, but don't know how I would fix it. I have a link which leads to a product. To describe this product even more, I added `meta` elements inside the `a` element to add stuff like product id, etc.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
            <meta property="productID" itemprop="productID" content="12">
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this through a validator I'm getting the error:

> Attribute `itemprop` not allowed on element `meta` at this point.

How would I define it otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `property` attribute and just do this:

```html
<meta itemprop="productID" content="12">
```

The `property` attribute is an RDFa attribute, not a Microdata attribute.

Comment: Okay, the validator doesn't throw any errors anymore. I tried that as well, but my IDE told me `Element meta doesn't have required attribute property` so I thought this was wrong. Is it valid though?

Comment: Yes it’s valid without the `property` attribute. If your IDE says otherwise, that”s a bug in the IDE.

Comment: Welp. I'm using JetBrain's IntelliJ. Since they got an active tracking system I'll open an issue there and will link this comment, k?

Comment: Ok, what about this one? `<meta name="twitter:description"  itemprop="description" content="my description goes here">`? It doesn't have `property` attribute. What's wrong then? (validator.w3.org throws error for that)